# How do you configure RRAS to use a different network segment for the VPN?

Tags: windows-server-2003, rras, windows-home-server

How do I configure RRAS to use a differnet network segment than my local network?

Is it possible to change the IP Address for the Internal network interface on RRAS?  And if so how do I do it?  I would like my VPN address range to be different than my local network.

(I am having problems with some machines trying to use this internal IP address for services.)

This is a Windows Home Server (Windows 2003) with SQLExpress 2005, IIS, RRAS for VPN support.

When trying to connect to connect to the SQL service soem of my workstation try to use the "Internal" interface instead of the "Local Area Connection" interface.

Local network is 192.168.2.0/24
I would like the VPN to be 192.168.254.0/24

Answer (score 1):

I found it...

In "Routing and Remote Access" right click on the server, click "Properties", go to the "IP" tab and then enter information for a "Static Address Pool"